# VBScript enable editing in Excel file & save as

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

```
Set obj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
obj.Visible = False
Set objwbk = obj.Workbooks.Open("File Link")
obj.DisplayAlerts = False
objwbk.SaveAs "C:\Data.xlsx"
Set obj1 = obj.Workbooks.Open("C:\Data.xlsx")
obj1.Visible = True
```

I have the above code to create a copy of the file on SharePoint. I am able to open the file but it does not make a copy because the file is opened in readonly mode. I am unable to figure out how to use the ActiveProtectedWindow.edit method here to be able to successfully achieve my objective.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
Set obj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
obj.Visible = False
obj.DisplayAlerts = False

Set objwbk = obj.Workbooks.Open("File Link")
If objwbk.Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Count > 0 Then
    objwbk.Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit
End If
objwbk.SaveAs "C:\Data.xlsx"
Set obj1 = obj.Workbooks.Open("C:\Data.xlsx")
obj1.Visible = True
```

Comment: Already tried that the objwbk.Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Count gives 0 & I get file not accessible error